# ffmpeg HTTP LIVE STREAMING remove old segments

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Hello i Have a Live HTTP stream input for ffmpeg 
i want to create HLS streaming im using ffmpeg to do this

```
ffmpeg -i http://127.0.0.1:4242/bysid/7275 -map 0 -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy -f ssegment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_type hls -segment_list_size 10 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts
```

i works fine i just want to delete the old segmens that are not shown in playlist.m3u8

```
segment_list_size 10
```

this will keep the last 10 in the playlist file i want to keep only these files on hard disk

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the recently added option to the HLS segmenter:

```
-hls_flags delete_segments
```

You will need to change your command to use the HLS segmenter rather than the stream segmenter by using -f hls instead of -f ssegment.

I've been using this option and it doesn't do exactly what you request, but rather it's implemented to be compliant with the HLS spec. See the ffmpeg documentation for more information: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html

Comment: I replaced -f segment to -f hls, but I got error: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invali
d argument

Comment: An example using -f hls and also  -hls_flags delete_segments:  

ffmpeg -v verbose -i "rtsp://admin:XXX@192.168.2.73:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0"  
-vf scale=1920:1080 -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -b:v 1000000 -crf 31 -an -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags delete_segments stream.m3u8

Answer (score 2):

USE

```
-segment_wrap 10
```

for wrap and rewrite segment files